# How to Merge Two Select Query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have below table structure in my `users` table where user and driver are saved with a unique `id` and separated with `user_type` column.  user ratings are being saved in `rider_avg_ratings` column and driver ratings are being saved in `driver_avg_ratings` column.

[image]

when a user submit a request it is being saved in `request`table with both userid and nearby driver id. now I have to return both driver ratings and user ratings from users table in a single query.Problem is when I join `request.userid=users.id` it is returning `rider_avg_ratings` to get the `driver_avg_ratings` i need to join `users.id=request.driver_id` how can I get both user and driver ratings from a single query

[image]

From above two table by joinning `request.user_id=users.id` I need to return `driver_avg_ratings=4.38` and `rider_avg_ratings=1.25`

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: no it is not showing any error only blank page

Comment: I do agree, with ysth. Guess you should get an error. There are certain constraints while you apply union or union all.  https://blog.udemy.com/sql-union-vs-union/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=DSA_Catchall_la.EN_cc.INDIA&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_82569850245_._ad_398023114490_._kw__._de_m_._dm__._pl__._ti_dsa-393987629421_._li_9061995_._pd__._&matchtype=b&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsfab3ra35gIVwpGPCh33gQ7xEAAYASAAEgKd7vD_BwE

Comment: no it's not showing any error

Comment: Ok. What is the expected output? According to docs (example given above), column numbers should match and need to be compatible. Can you check and let know of expected output?

Comment: I have driver and user ratings in the same users table.As I join users table with bid_request table i am getting only user ratings but I need both driver and user ratings.I am trying to get the driver ratings by union

Comment: Is individual query returning results you require? Can you get the headers of individual results and union result here? Did you check on constraints of union query I mentioned above?

Comment: individual query not returning my required results but returning results.Problem is both driver and user ratings are in users table.when i am joining users table with bid_request table by user id reference i am not getting driver ratings rather user ratings only but i need both. I think my query is similar to your provided link but why showing blank result can't figure out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204295/discussion-between-g-shenoy-and-mithu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT r.user_id as userId, u.rider_avg_ratings as ratings 
FROM user as u 
INNER JOIN request as r on u.id = r.user_id 

UNION 

SELECT r1.driver_id as userId, u1.driver_avg_ratings as ratings 
FROM user as u1 
INNER JOIN request as r1 on u1.id = r1.driver_id
```

This query will fetch the desired result.

Comment: Thanks its returning results. If I want to use a where statement then is it needed to be included in both statement

Answer (score 0):

Your union query should produce a `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns` error.  You need to figure out why your code isn't checking for errors and make it do so.  Also, if this is the entire statement, the parentheses around it don't belong.

You need to make the two unioned selects return the same number of parameters.  Note that `as` in the second select's select columns will be ignored and result column names will come from the first select only.  Minimally, to make the query run, you would need to add `,NULL,NULL,...` to your second select, but it seems likely you want more information to be able to identify which user the driver_avg_ratings is for, like the id, name, etc the first query is returning.

It's often helpful when processing the results to add something indicating which select a row came from, too, e.g. `SELECT "pending_request_users" AS type, ... UNION ALL SELECT "all_users_avg_rating", ...`.

Note that the different SELECTs unioned together return entire rows.  If your only goal is to add driver ratings to the rows already returned, you don't want a union, you may just want to add:

```
SELECT ..., driver.driver_avg_ratings
FROM user u
...
INNER JOIN user AS driver ON driver.id=req.driver_id
```

(or left join if there may not be a driver_id).  But it's hard to tell for sure if that's what you want.  Provide sample data and your desired results from it.  In any case, do make your code detect errors properly.

Comment: I have tried adding Null on 2nd select statement to match no of columns in both but not working. Basically I have id, driver_avg_ratings,User_avg_ratings and type column in users table. in types users are saved us user and drivers are saved as driver value. in request table i have user_id and driver_id. now when i join two table by user_id it is returning user_avg_ratings but i need driver_avg_ratings as well. To get driver_avg_ratings i must join driver_id from request table with user table id column . I have attached an image here with both table structure https://imgur.com/a/1lt1vFu

Comment: Images are hard to read and incomplete; much better to just copy the output of `show create table yourtablename` into your question, for each of your tables.  And even more important would be showing some sample data and what your desired results are

Comment: What results do you want?  The query at the end of my answer is the best guess I can make without seeing actual sample data and your desired results from that data.

Comment: apologize, i have edited my question again with expected result

Comment: Doesn't my query do that?

Answer (score 0):

for example:
Department
1 A
2 B
3 A
4 C
5 B
6 D
7 E
8 F

**You could do something like**

SELECT
    1 AS Deptnumber
  , Dept
FROM tbl_students
WHERE Dept IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
UNION
SELECT
    2 AS DeptNumber
  , Dept
FROM tbl_students
WHERE Dept IN ('D', 'E')
UNION
SELECT
    3 AS Deptnumber
  , Dept
FROM tbl_students
WHERE Dept IN ('F')

Comment: its looking very confusing to me. can you edited your answer based on my provided table and column pls